# Customer cannot login to magento 1.8.1

Tags: php, magento

customer unable to login in magento 1.8.1 
when i set cookie path '/tmp' and domain 'mydomain.com' from the backend then customer can login but admin cannot login.

I'm very new to magento. Please Help me how to fix that?

Comment: Is it a upgraded Magento?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try after setting secure and unsecure base url in backend like following sample.

[image]

Comment: Ok. Then try after commenting `$this->renewSession();` in `app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/session.php` file. And if it works then build the following directory hierarchy: app/code/local/Mage/Customer/Model/. Put a copy of session.php into this new directory.