# Can't log in to Magento admin backend

Tags: php, magento, xampp, backend, magento-1.9

I have installed Magento 1.9 into the htdocs of xampp, using the theme Milano. The front end seems to be working perfectly well but I cant access the back end.

As you can see, there are 2 input text boxes for password! I know the user name and password and have tried several combinations to somehow log in, but the output is always this page.

I'm a newbie here so please bear with me. Thanks already.

Comment: "as you can see". see what? you didn't include anything in your question

Comment: Try with different browser

Comment: var/session and var/cache clear cache and session

Comment: sorry it wouldnt allow me to post images. never mind i solved it. thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

This is a consequence of having magento locally. To fix this you have to comment out some code roughly placed in code/core/mage/core/session/varien....if I am remembering the path correctly there should be only one file in this directory and your looking for a chunk of code tracking cookies

Answer (score 0):

As Chris Richardson says, it is a problem caused by local installation.
To "trick" your browser, add a virtualhost in xampp for your local magento, and add a entry to host file:
`127.0.0.1 www.example.dev`
where www.example.dev must match the host name you give when you create the virtualhost.

Answer (score 0):

You can change secure and unsecure url as follows.

[Customer cannot login to magento 1.8.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28171657/customer-cannot-login-to-magento-1-8-1/28172597#28172597)

After setting this, it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You can find solution here 
I think your problem will be solved with this thread 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15491865/5083109